# pdf latex auto open url or hyperlink

Tags: pdftex, luatex, pdf, urls, href

This example is latex, a line code using automatic. Did not find any related answers about this

\href{https://google.com} {autopen}

How to open auto hyperlink via pdf latex. Like opening the pdf, the link will be auto-executed. Any ideas

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you add what the use case for this is please? It would be easy to link to a malicious URL so I do not advise this, if I opened a PDF that automatically opened unknown websites I would delete it and never accept a document from that person again

Comment: latex just generates pdf it can not implement interaction not supported by the pdf standard or viewer. How would you want this to work, a pdf viewer can't normally show an html page. even web browsers have restrictions on opening other pages with no human interaction as that has rather large privacy implications